# Как оформлять примечания в ответе?

Tags: оформление-текста

В свои ответы я порой вставляю примечания. Иногда одно примечание, иногда несколько. Как их лучше оформлять (в обоих случаях)? Если примечание одно и состоит из одного предложения, можно ли дать его после двоеточия со строчной буквы (*Примечание: текст*)? Если примечаний много, можно ли написать "Примечания" как заголовок (без точки), а под ним поместить нумерованный список? Следуя [Мильчину](https://books.google.ee/books?id=N2p6GFY7PXkC&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5,%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C.%20%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80.:%20%20%D0%9D%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0:&source=bl&ots=df6C1zxTNA&sig=wbIzsdIb1v9cuEJ1mCxD9pTyE6A&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiU0u3qwKzfAhUB_iwKHSgEAuoQ6AEwAXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C.%20%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80.%3A%20%20%D0%9D%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%3A&f=false), если я правильно понимаю, нужно воспринимать слово "Примечания" как слово, предшествующее перечню, тогда после него ставится двоеточие, а элементы перечня могут начинаться с прописной.

У Розенталя по-другому:

> Примечание. О написании союзов чтобы и также см §61, пп. 1, 2.

-

> Примечание 1. Если частица....
>   Примечание 2. Частица как будто...

Answer (score 2):

Вот инструкция для студентов по оформлению работ:

Слово «Примечание» следует печатать с прописной буквы с абзаца.

Если примечание одно, после слова «Примечание» ставится тире и примечание печатается с прописной буквы.

Пример оформления одного примечания:

Примечание – Оформление таблиц соответствует ГОСТ 1.5 и ГОСТ 2.105

6.7.3 Несколько примечаний нумеруются по порядку арабскими цифрами.

Пример оформления нескольких примечаний:

Примечания

1 – Внесение исправлений соответствует ГОСТ 13.1.002

2 – Сокращение русских слов соответствует ГОСТ 7.12

Здесь советуют то же самое: https://studfiles.net/preview/6207803/page:3/

Comment: Там (по ссылке) в примере стоят арабские цифры без точки и без тире (?!)

Comment: Видимо, есть варианты. Вот, например:"напишите слово «Примечания» с заглавной буквы. Точку не ставьте. Каждое примечание пишите с новой строки после арабской цифры: «Рассмотрев график среднесуточной температуры в Москве и Московской области в конце января, ученые пришли к следующему выводу. Примечания 1. Данный график отражает изменения среднесуточной температуры, наблюдаемые в сельской местности. 2. График справедлив при условии использования стандартных приборов учета влажности и атмосферного давления».
Подробнее: https://www.kakprosto.ru/kak-103068-kak-oformit-primechanie#ixzz5atHWK9I1

Comment: Применительно к данному сайту что Вы посоветуете: как у Розенталя или как в студенческой работе? И не скажете ли,  Розенталь на какой страндарт опирался?

Comment: Мне нравится с цифрами и точкой, без тире. А Розенталь ориентировался на то, что при перечислении примечаний имеется в виду, что это тире перед предполагаемым "это": Первое - это ...